# SQL dealing with duplicates caused by changing collation

Tags: sql-server

I had to change my database collation and all columns collation from an AS to an AI.

Some of the records were part of table keys, so now I have wrong duplicity in the base.

```
X    Y    DATE
1    à    2015-08-01 00:00:20
2    a    2015-08-01 00:00:23
```

X and Y are table keys.

How can I solve that? I was thinking in a script to replace all the accent characters to an normal character between []. Example "ábc" would become "[a]bc". But i d have to do that before changing the collation of course.

Does anyone has a better solution to this?

Comment: Why do you need to change the collation on a _key_ column? Did you know you can have different collations on different columns in a table? Normally you would change collation on a searchable type attribute. Please explain further

Comment: Yes. Let me try to explain better. Supose you have your database with all the collumns with an AS collation. Some of these columns are keys to your table. Now for some reason you need to change all collation colouns of your base to an AI. Causing your base to considere wrong duplicates. I need to keep storing an "à" different from "a" in a column with AI collation, i know it sounds crazy, but thats the requirement i am facing..

Comment: and what is that 'some reason' that you need to change an internal key? it is an internal key right? or have you mixed internal keys and external attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but it was because i was changing character set as well.

old collation: SQL_Latin1_General_**CP1253**_CI_AS

new collation: SQL_Latin1_General_**CP1**_CI_AI

In my case, it was only necessary changing it to accent insensitive. So i used the following one and there were no duplicated rows:

SQL_Latin1_General_**CP1253**_CI_AI